# Consulta en cadena

Tags: c, string, struct

este apartado del programa no me acaba de funcionar. En ocasiones me da un bucle infinito o en este caso no me busca nada.
Teniendo en cuenta que ind_alumne es una variable global.
Tenemos que alumnes es una struct de alumne, que previamente he añadido 1 alumno dentro.
Alguna sugerencia??
El strcmp lo hago para que compare las 2 cadenas.

```
void consulta_dni()
{
    char temporal[MAXDNI];
    int tmp=0;
    system("CLS");
    printf("Introdueix el dni a buscar: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",temporal[tmp]);fflush(stdin);
    if(strcmp(temporal[tmp],alumnes[ind_alumne].dni)==0){
    printf("%s\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].nom);
    printf("%s\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].dni);
    printf("%i/%i/%i",alumnes[ind_alumne].naixement.dia,alumnes[ind_alumne].naixement.mes,alumnes[ind_alumne].naixement.year);
    printf("%f\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].nota);
    ind_alumne++;
  }
  else{
      printf("No existeix el DNI!!\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, pon código, no imágenes. Las imágenes se ven peor que el código y su contenido no se puede seleccionar, copiar ni pegar. Además, si la imagen deja de estar disponible pasado un tiempo, la pregunta dejará de tener sentido, al ser en este caso la imagen una parte fundamental de la pregunta

Comment: Listo! Pensaba que la imagen duraba para siempre...@eferion

Comment: La imagen se aloja en servidores externos y nadie garantiza su disponibilidad. Piensa que ocupa un espacio en un disco y eso se traduce en costes - dinero. Si nadie los paga está claro que en algún momento desaparecerá

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` requiere dos punteros de tipo `char`:

```
 if(strcmp(temporal[tmp],alumnes[ind_alumne].dni)==0){
```

Está claro que `temporal` es un array de tipo `char`:

```
char temporal[MAXDNI];
```

Sin embargo, `temporal[tmp]` es un **char**. Esa comparación nunca te va a funcionar. `strcmp` va a coger el char como si fuese un puntero, es decir, el valor del `char` se va a asumir que es una dirección de memoria y se va a intentar acceder a dicha dirección de memoria.

Lo que tienes que hacer es

```
if(strcmp(temporal,alumnes[ind_alumne].dni)==0){
```

Y, ya puestos, por favor, tabula el código correctamente. Así:

```
if(strcmp(temporal[tmp],alumnes[ind_alumne].dni)==0){
    printf("%s\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].nom);
    printf("%s\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].dni);
    printf("%i/%i/%i",alumnes[ind_alumne].naixement.dia,
                      alumnes[ind_alumne].naixement.mes,
                      alumnes[ind_alumne].naixement.year);
    printf("%f\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].nota);
    ind_alumne++;
}
else{
    printf("No existeix el DNI!!\n");
}
```

Comment: Vale, lo tengo cambiado. Es posible que el error esté en los printf para imprimir los datos?? O tendría que usar un boolean para encontrar? @eferion

Comment: Ni idea. Piensa por ejemplo que ahí no tienes ningún bucle, luego es imposible que en esa porción de código tengas un bucle infinito ... de la misma manera que en un desierto no puedes morir ahogado

Answer (score 0):

```
void consulta_dni()
{
    char dni[MAXDNI];   //Guardar el dni aqui!!
    int index=0;        //Recorrer la cadena de arriba
    int trobat=0;
    int ind_alumne=0;
    system("CLS");
    printf("Introdueix el dni a buscar: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",&dni);fflush(stdin);
    if(strcmp(dni,alumnes[ind_alumne].dni)==0 && !trobat){
      printf("Nom: %s\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].nom);
      printf("Dni: %s\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].dni);
      printf("Data Naixement: %i/%i/%i\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].naixement.dia,
                                          alumnes[ind_alumne].naixement.mes,
                                          alumnes[ind_alumne].naixement.year);
      printf("Nota: %i\n",alumnes[ind_alumne].nota);
      index++;
      ind_alumne++;
  }
  else{
     printf("No existeix el DNI!!\n");
  }
  printf("Pulsa intro para continuar...\n");
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: Ahora lo tengo esta manera, me lee el DNI y hace la busqueda y me muestra todos los datos. El problema ha surgido cuando he introducido 2 usuarios diferentes y solo me guarda el 1r usuario. Alguna idea de como rematarlo del todo??@eferion